# How to concatenate numeric columns in R?

Tags: r, concatenation

I have three columns of x, y, and z coordinates in a dataframe in R that I would like to concatenate into one xyz value, like below. I have tried 'paste' with 'collapse'="" and sep="" but am having trouble, I think it's something to do with text vs. numeric variables.

```
I have:
x y z 
1 2 3 
2 3 2 
3 1 4 
4 2 1 

I want:
x y z xyz
1 2 3 123
2 3 2 232
3 1 4 314
4 2 1 421
```

There has to be some extremely easy/simple way to do this in R but I have been Googling and looking through Stack Overflow off-and-on for the past couple days and nothing has come to my attention. All I need is the xyz column to be unique so I can run fixed-effects regressions, (x ranges from 1:4, y from 1:4 and z 1:10) so I have 160 possible combinations. Currently I am using different exponents on the x, y, and z values and then multiplying them to get unique values--surely there's a better way! Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For example:

```
transform(df,xyz=paste0(x,y,z))
  x y z xyz
1 1 2 3 123
2 2 3 2 232
3 3 1 4 314
4 4 2 1 421
```

Or using `interaction`:

```
transform(df,xyz=interaction(x,y,z,sep=''))
  x y z xyz
1 1 2 3 123
2 2 3 2 232
3 3 1 4 314
4 4 2 1 421
```

`

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple with paste that I was missing.

Comment: Or, as a generalization, `df$xyz <- do.call(paste0, df)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
df$NewCol <- do.call(paste, c(df[c("x", "y", "z")], sep = ""))
```

Answer (score 3):

Two other options for combining columns are `dplyr::mutate()` and `tidyr::unite()`:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'x y z 
                 1 2 3 
                 2 3 2 
                 3 1 4 
                 4 2 1', header = T)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(xyz_char = paste0(x, y, z)) %>%           
  mutate(xyz_num = as.numeric(paste0(x, y, z)))
```

Note that using `paste()` converts numeric values to character. You'd need to wrap it with `as.numeric()` to keep the field as a numeric value, if that's what you needed.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  unite(xyz, x:z, sep = '', remove = FALSE)
```

The default argument in `tidy::unite()` is `remove = TRUE`, which drops the original columns from the data frame.